# Why does 515236034100068353 is equal to 515236034100068350 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, transformation

I was in need to use the number *51523603410006835**3*** but JavaScript transforms it as *51523603410006835**0***

[image]

```js
console.log(515236034100068353 === 515236034100068350)
```

Why does this happens ? How could I fix it ?

Comment: `How could I fix it ?` use BigInts, not numbers (`123n`)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint has a good explanation of what is going on.